# Excel Workbook Activate Event Ambiguity for C# VSTO

Tags: vsto, excel

Here is the error:

```
Error   2   Cannot assign to 'Activate' because it is a 'method group'  
Warning 1   Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.Activate()' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookEvents_Event.Activate'. Using method group.
```

I can use

```
myWorkbook.Deactivate += new Excel.WorkbookEvents_DeactivateEventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Deactivate);
```

because there is no deactivate() method for a workbook.  There is a Activate() method, which i DO NOT want to use. I'm wanting to handle the workbook Activate event like this, but i get the error above

```
myWorkbook.Activate += new Excel.WorkbookEvents_ActivateEventHandler(ThisWorkbook_Activate);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here http://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/category/vsto/vsto-issues/

"Activate is both a method and an event of Application.Excel, so the Activate keyword must be cast to either an event or method."