# Ambiguity Between Workbook Event And Method E.g. Sync

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, events, ambiguity

I am getting an ambiguity error that seems to be between an event and a property name. I have a class that is implementing the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook` interface and decorating it with extra logic. The interface is being implemented via a private variable of type Workbook. I used the Visual Studio shortcut to implement the interface via this private member. But I'm getting some errors relating to ambiguity.

For example, there is a property called Sync which is of type Microsoft.Office.Core.Sync. There is also an event called Sync. Both show up as errors for me. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
class WorkbookDecoratorImpl : Workbook
{
   private Workbook _workbook;       
   public Microsoft.Office.Core.Sync Sync => _workbook.Sync;  
   event WorkbookEvents_SyncEventHandler WorkbookEvents_Event.Sync
    {
        add
        {
            _workbook.Sync += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            _workbook.Sync -= value;
        }
    }
```

I get errors on both the event and the property, saying:

> Ambiguity between 'WorkbookEvents_Event.Sync' and '_Workbook.Sync'

I get a similar error for Activate, but in this case only on the event override:

```
event WorkbookEvents_ActivateEventHandler WorkbookEvents_Event.Activate
{
    add
    {
        _workbook.Activate += value;
    }

    remove
    {
        _workbook.Activate -= value;
    }
}
```

In this case I get:

```
error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'Activate' because it is a 'method group'
```

## Notes

Visual Studio seems to have been smart enough to avoid ambiguity in *naming* the event by prefixing it with "WorkbookEvents_Event.". In the case of Open, we don't have the same ambiguity and Visual Studio didn't prefix:

```
public event WorkbookEvents_OpenEventHandler Open
```

Comment: Oh, I may have found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610285/excel-workbook-activate-event-ambiguity-for-c-sharp-vsto

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular case by looking online here: https://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/category/vsto/vsto-issues/. I retrieved the reference from this question: [Excel Workbook Activate Event Ambiguity for C# VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610285/excel-workbook-activate-event-ambiguity-for-c-sharp-vsto).

I'll spell out the solution here to my specific problem. For the Sync method:

```
public Microsoft.Office.Core.Sync Sync => ((_Workbook) _workbook).Sync;
```

For the Sync event:

```
event WorkbookEvents_SyncEventHandler WorkbookEvents_Event.Sync
    {
        add
        {
            ((WorkbookEvents_Event) _workbook).Sync += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            ((WorkbookEvents_Event) _workbook).Sync -= value;
        }
    }
```

Activate event was similar to Sync event.